# TSQL : Want to use compress method on existing nvarchar(max) column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an existing data column of type nvarchar(max) , I wanted to use the compress function before storing data on this column to reduce the size of the data.
Technically its working fine in below queries , I know for compressed data we should ideally be using column of type varbinary(max) but just wanted to understand the issues may arise if I'll use existing nvarchar(max) for storing inbuilt compress function data.

Queries working fine with nvarchar(max) type:

```
create table test (
name nvarchar(MAX)
)

insert into test ( name) values (COMPRESS(cast('hello how are you im fine thanks' as nvarchar(max))))

select cast(DECOMPRESS(cast(name as varbinary(max))) as nvarchar(max)) as name from test
```

Thanks in Advance
Abdul

Comment: Are you simply asking "why" you should use `varbinary` instead of `mvarchar(MAX)`? I'd suggest the reason is because compressed data (until it it decompressed) is just "nonsense" data when tried to be displayed; `COMPRESS` specifically stores the data in byte arrays. You *could*, I suppose store the data as an `nvarchar`, but you'll end up with values like `N'謟'` if you query your data without decompression.

Comment: Thanks Larnu , yes in query it will come-up like this but for varbinary type also we have the same problem.  I just wanted to know is there any other problem if I use my existing nvarchar(max) column to store the varbinary data of inbuilt compress function?

Comment: Personally, I would use the proper varbinary(MAX) type as it will only cause confusion for subsequent developers if you use nvarchar for binary data.